# sql query notification service issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We are getting timeout issues on our databases. So I trurned on SQL Server Profiler and see SQLQueryNotificationService running every second with long duration. I checked the Service Broker and there are bunch of SQLQueryNotificationService queues created. I don't think we created any of these queues also there are bunch of stored procedures like these SqlQueryNotificationStoredProcedure-15c5b84b-42b0-4cfb-9707-9b1697f44127. Could you please let me know how to drop them? If I drop them is there any impact on the database? Please let me know. I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What is the nature of the timeout?  Are you getting timeouts when attempting to connect?  Or are certain queries taking too long to run?  There are a lot of factors involved in database performance, such as network size/performance/latency, table sizes, indexes, query throughput, client connections, etc.  I think it would be wise to step back and examine your overall system before jumping to the conclusion that you need to start wiping out internal stored procedures.

Comment: Sometimes Timeout occurs when calling the the stored procedures and sometimes they are not even getting called. The same code worked fine without any issues last month. This month we started noticing this timeout issue. We didn't change any stored procedures or any queries.

Comment: That's a pretty common pattern when you have tables that are growing in size over time.  You need to take a specific example and try to address the timeout.  For instance, if you have a stored procedure that reads data from a table with thousands of rows and it needs to complete in less than 30 seconds, consider indexing the columns that are used in filtering (i.e., `WHERE` clause).  You can also increase the timeout length in your client code - timeouts are [entirely client-side](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/khen1234/archive/2005/10/20/483015.aspx) and can usually be made indefinitely long.

Comment: Can you give some example of your code that is timing out, and the structure and sizes of tables involved?  Also, what do you mean by "sometimes they are not even getting called"?  If a stored procedure is not able to run (because the database is overloaded or you've hit your connection limit, for example), you should at least get some sort of error message.

Comment: We tried to increase timeout length but didn't help.

Comment: You are really going to need to include more details about your setup if you want more help.  Saying things like "that didn't help" and "it doesn't work" gets us nowhere.  What does your stored procedure look like?  Can you paste the entire contents of it into, say, [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and provide a link?  You still haven't answered some of my other questions (like what do you mean by the procedure not even getting called?)  Can you try running each step of your stored procedure one at a time in a tool like SSMS and see which part is taking the longest?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have an ASP.Net web site running or another application that creates Sql Server Cache dependencies? It is Sql Server Service Broker queues, it executes that WAITFOR ... statement which waits for around one minute (60000 msecs), then executes again next second. Shouldn't normally cause problems, it shouldn't block or delay your "normal" queries or stored procedures.

However, I saw it causing issues for me once - one of the stored procedures, when executed from the same web application that established the cache dependency, did timeout (or rather came back in 120 secs which is not acceptable). Exactly the same stored procedure, executed under the same account with same parameters, but from Management Studio, ran fine without any issues. It was SQL Server 2005 SP4.

SQL Profiler showed that in the middle of execution of my stored procedure (and always after the same INSERT INTO ... statement), its execution was interrupted and instead of its statement there was that WAIT FOR .... from Sql Query Notification, completed in one minute, then another WAIT FOR... starting and again, completed in 59 secs - and only after that the Profiler showed me my stored procedure completed. With the duration of 119000, which is almost exactly two minutes.

It was if that query notifications were joining the transaction within my stored procedure.

**What helped:** recompiled the offending stored procedure. I simply changed its script, did ALTER statement with some minor syntax changes. No problems after that.

Comment: and yes, now its time for reflection, why it helped and what was wrong in the first place.